# Git Clone Error: The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: git, git-clone

We had bitbucket over http till recently and it was working fine. We are behind proxy.
Recently we changed bitbucket to https and then we started getting this error.

The issue is as soon as we enter the git command, we are not prompted for credentials which was not the case earlier. 
I tried providing credentials in git command like  **`git clone https:\\username:password@repourl.git`** .Still same error.

Telnet works fine to the bitbucket server.
SSL connection also works fine.

The exact error is **`fatal: unable to access 'https://ourbitbucket.dummy/vcs/scm/devops/docker-builds.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403`**

```
⚡ root@dummyserver ~ cd gitrepo
 ⚡ root@dummyserver ~/gitrepo git clone https://ourbitbucket.dummy/vcs/scm/devops/docker-builds.git
Cloning into 'docker-builds'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://ourbitbucket.dummy/vcs/scm/devops/docker-builds.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
 ✘ ⚡ root@dummyserver ~/gitrepo 
 ✘ ⚡ root@dummyserver ~/gitrepo telnet ourbitbucket.dummy 443
Trying 10.82.25.14...
Connected to ourbitbucket.dummy.
Escape character is '^]'.
^CConnection closed by foreign host.
 ✘ ⚡ root@dummyserver ~/gitrepo cd ..
 ⚡ root@dummyserver ~ java SSLPoke ourbitbucket.dummy 443
Successfully connected
```

Any idea whats wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> we are not prompted for credentials which was not the case earlier.

Check first if this is because the (wrong) credentials are cached and used automatically by Git

```
root@dummyserver
  git config credential.helper
```

If there is an entry for `https://ourbitbucket.dummy`, that would explain why there is no credential prompt.

Check also if there is a proxy configuration (`git config -l | grep -i proxy`) or a `NO_PROXY` environment variable (which might avoid the proxy for http URL, but not for https URL): `env|grep -i proxy`.

Comment: `root@ln228pdevopsctl  ~/gitrepo  git config credential.helper`                      

   
`cache`                    : ( output)        

`git config -l | grep -i proxy              

           
http.proxy=http://username:password@proxy.dummy:8080    
https.proxy=http://username:password@proxy.dummy:8080`    

No_Proxy is set with ourbitbucket.dummy. How do we set for https url.

Comment: @VVP "No_Proxy is set with ourbitbucket.dummy. H" means you do not want to use the proxy, which is fine. Nothing to set for https there. But a cache credentials means the wrong credentials might be set by https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache. Try exiting the GIt cache daemon, jsut for testing and try a clone again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to access a intranet/company bitbucket, you might not need a proxy to access it.
If you are trying to access the company intranet bitbucket with a proxy, you can get the error 403.

If that is the case, you can try unsetting the proxy for the bitbucket address, for example:

```
export no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.*,<example.bitbucket.company.com>
export NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.*,<example.bitbucket.company.com>
```

After setting it, please check if no_proxy is correctly set by executing the following commands, if in bash:

```
echo $no_proxy
```

and

```
echo $NO_PROXY
```

You can also permanently set your proxies environmental variables and/or check if your proxies are set correctly across your linux.
In both cases, this post can help you to check the environmental variables possible locations: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249922/525771
For RedHat, you can check here: https://access.redhat.com/articles/2133021